# Passing arguments in the __init__ method

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

```
class database:
   def __init__(self):
      self.db_port = 3306
      self.db_host = "mysql.rs.org'
```

I thought we had to initialize the class by passing arguments to the `__init__` method, like so:

```
class database:
   def __init__(self, db_port, db_host):
      self.db_port = db_port
      self.db_host = db_host
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What's the actual problem here?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly your question is. At the moment it is not clear what you are asking and is very likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it the first way will make all your *database* objects to be the same. Doing it the other way will let you to set the attributes to anything you want as you create them. Both are fine to do but the second one is more dynamic. It all depends if your program will ever need a *database* object with different *db_port* and *db_host* than 3306 and "mysql.rs.org'.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for the help.